# Unrecognized Selector Error when writing dictionary values to file in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, dictionary, alassetslibrary

I'm reading an array of ALAsset objects (delcared as `NSMutableArray *assets;` in the header file). I'm trying to follow [this example](http://iphonedevelopertips.com/data-file-management/read-and-write-array-dictionary-and-other-collections-to-files.html) in order to print the contents of an ALAssets dictionary to file to be retrieved later. Note that I can properly write the dictionary key to file (commented out), but not the value.

Here is my code which runs at the end of the viewDidLoad() method:

```
// Create path to Documents
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

if ([paths count] > 0) {
    NSString *dictPath = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"dict.out"];
    NSDictionary *aDict = [[assets objectAtIndex:0] valueForProperty:ALAssetPropertyURLs];

    for (id key in aDict) {
        NSLog(@"key: %@, value: %@", key, [aDict valueForKey:key]);  
        //[key writeToFile:dictPath atomically:YES];        <- THIS LINE WORKS
        [[aDict valueForKey:key] writeToFile:dictPath atomically:YES];            
    }
}
else
    NSLog(@"nope");    // The program doesn't get here.
```

The log looks like this:

> 2011-11-17 23:44:41.340 PhotoApp[542:12803] key: public.jpeg,
>   value: assets-library://asset/asset.JPG?id=1000000001&ext=JPG
>
> 2011-11-17 23:44:41.361 PhotoApp[542:12803] -[NSURL
>   writeToFile:atomically:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
>   0x6455650
>
> 2011-11-17 23:44:41.370 PhotoApp[542:12803] ***
>   Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSURL
>   writeToFile:atomically:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
>   0x6455650'

---

**Edit**: Not sure whether it matters, but the project is targeted for iPad, and is running on the simulator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method `writeToFile:atomically:` is available only for NSDictionary and NSArray. Actually you have NSURLs objects in the `aDict` dictionary. Even for NSString, that has been deprecated actually.

Since you are obtaining the URLs, get the NSURL's absoluteString (which returns NSString) from them and write them to file using `writeToFile:atomically:encoding:error:`

Otherwise you can write the `aDict` (NSDictionary) object itself to a file.

Comment: Thanks. So I take it there isn't a way to change the type of an NSURL object?

Comment: This works but writing the `NSDictionary` object may be nicer, especially when reading back from the file. The link in my question shows this for a dictionary of strings (which I could replicate) but I could not do it for my dictionary. Should the implementation be the same?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is 
`[[aDict valueForKey:key] writeToFile:dictPath atomically:YES];` line.

as in `key: public.jpeg, value: assets-library://asset/asset.JPG?id=1000000001&ext=JPG`

you get the
 ***key*** as `public.jpeg` and ***value*** as

```
asassets-library://asset/asset.JPG?id=1000000001&ext=JPG
```

which is a `NSURL` object so when you  use.

```
[[aDict valueForKey:key] writeToFile:dictPath atomically:YES];
```

code then `[aDict valueForKey:key]` return `NSURL` object which does not recognizes `writeToFile`: method.